# How to make numbers fade in instead of popping up

Tags: javascript, css

Okay so this is a bit hard to explain this, but I am trying to make where whenever a number is "spawned" or generated, it fades in instead of just popping up.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mox/hfsk8751/) is the Fiddle that I am trying to do that with. I am using a `input` tag for the number and a `for` statement to generate the rest--

```
for (I = 0; I < $("#input:text").val(); I++) {
        N.innerHTML += 1 + I + " "
    }
```

I hope I explained that well enough so people understand!

Comment: why you mix `jquery` and `javascript` together?

Comment: jsfiddle is not working.You are writing In = D.getElementById("input"),
    ..... and again using jQuery id selector on In
$(In).keyup(function(Key) {

Comment: The fiddle works fine for me, i'm just trying to make the numbers fade in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Append `span` elements instead of `text` so that you can easily select elements using selector.

Use `setTimeout` to make it happen serially using `index`.

Try this:

```js
var D = document,
  In = D.getElementById("input"),
  CC = D.getElementById("submit"),
  N = D.getElementById("N"),
  I;

$(In).keyup(function(Key) {
  if (Key.keyCode == 13) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $("#input:text").val().length; i++) {
      var span = '<span style=\'display:none\'>' + (i + 1) + ' ' + $("#input:text").val()[i] + ' </span>'; //set display of `span` element as `none`
      N.innerHTML += span;
    }
  }
  $('#N span').each(function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).hide().fadeIn(500);
    }.bind(this), (i * 500)); // `.bind()` will pass the outer `this` context in`setTimeout` when handler is invoked
  })
});

$(CC).click(function() {
  N.innerHTML = "";
});
```

```css
body {
  cursor: default;
  outline-width: 0px;
}
#main {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <input type="text" id="input" maxlength="3" placeholder="Press submit to clear all" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
  </div>
  <h1 id="N"></h1>
</body>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/hfsk8751/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) method would make this trivial.  But if you want to do this with no libraries you can modify the opacity of the result div in a recursive loop. I modified your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t84ksd1x/1/) and included it below.  The key points are setting the result div to opacity:0 at start, then recursively calling the "fadeIn" function after your original code has ran. you can tweak the timeout delay and opacity increment to get the desired speed and smoothness of the fade effect.

*HTML:*

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <input type="text" id="input" maxlength="3" placeholder="Press submit to clear all" />
    <input type="submit" id="clear" />
  </div>
  <h1 id="N"></h1>
</body>
```

*CSS:*

```
body {
  cursor: default;
  outline-width: 0px;
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
}

#N {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

*JavaScript:*

```
var D = document,
  In = D.getElementById("input"),
  CC = D.getElementById("clear"),
  N = D.getElementById("N"),
  I,
  O = 0;

var fadeIn = function() {

  O += 0.05
  D.getElementById("N").style.opacity = O;

  if (O < 1) {
    setTimeout(fadeIn, 100)
  }
}

$(In).keyup(function(Key) {
  if (Key.keyCode == 13) {
    for (I = 0; I < $("#input:text").val(); I++) {
      N.innerHTML += 1 + I + " "
    }
    setTimeout(fadeIn, 100)
  }
});

$(CC).click(function() {
  N.innerHTML = "";
});
```